# RegEx and an optional string

Tags: regex, string

I am having problems with an optional group in a regex (.NET syntax, and I'm using RegexOptions.Singleline).

`"function (\w*).*?{(?:.*?\((.*?)\))?.*?}"`

Also tried, to no avail:
`"function (\w*)[^{]+{(?:.*?\((.*?)\))?.*?}"`

It looks like the group is not optional, because if I just add two parenthesis in FunctionWithNoParameters then all is working fine. The goal is to have two groups: the function name and their optional parameters. Can someone help me?

The text I'm trying to parse is something like:

```
 function test1
{
    param ([int]$parm2, [bool]$parm3)
}

function FunctionWithNoParameters { 

return "nothing"
}

function test2    {
  param([string]$parm1, 
        [int]$parm2, 
        [bool]$parm3)}
```

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: You don’t want to parse a non-regular language with a regular expression, do you?

Comment: No, I'm not. That would probably not the best approach for that problem ;)

I am trying to get all the functions (and their parameters) in a Powershell script...

Answer (score 1):

This regex works for me given the sample data you provided:

```
@"function\s+(\w+)\s*\{\s*(?:param\s*\(([^()]*)\))?"
```

The main problem with your regex is this part: `.*?\(`. When you match the second function, the `.*?` scans all the way through that function and finds the opening parenthesis in the third function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function (?<name>\w+)\s*?\{\s*?(?<param>param\s*\([\s\S]*?\))?[\s\S]*?\}
```

**EDIT:** Strange, I couldn't match that optional `param` group in my tests

Comment: A combination of the two could do the trick I think:
`function (\w*)[^{]+{\s*(?<param>param\s*\([\s\S]*?\))?.*?}`

but...now I get the word "param" and the parenthesis as well.